# AsyncStorage not work - react native

Tags: react-native

I want to use `AsyncStorage` as set and get value but it doesnt work inside `componentDidMount`:

```
componentDidMount(){

    commonHelper.setData('mmmm','12345');
    commonHelper.getData('mmmm')
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data)
    });

 }
```

---

my `commonHelper.js`

```
function getData(key) {
  try {
       const value = AsyncStorage.getItem(key).then(val => {
         return val
       });
       return value
     } catch (err) {
       throw err
     }
}

function setData(key,value) {
  try {
    AsyncStorage.setItem(key, value);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error saving data" + error);
  }
}
```

Comment: AsyncStorage is asynchronous. You must wait for `setItem` to be fulfilled before using `getItem`.

Answer (score 0):

As [Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2026768/dan) recommended, use it asyncronously:

```
import { setData } from './commonHelper';

  ...

  componentDidMount(){
    commonHelper.setData('mmmm','12345')
    .then(() => { /* do something. The data is stored now. */});
  }


//commonHelper.js

export async function setData(key, value) {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, value);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error saving data" + error);
  }
}
```

Comment: For your example to work, `setData` must return the Promise. `const setData = (key, value) => AsyncStorage.setItem(key, value)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { setData } from '../commonHelper';

componentDidMount() {
  this.updateStorage();
}

updateStorage = async () => {
  const item = await setData('mmmm','12345');
  console.log({
    item
  });
}
```

CommonHelper function:

```
export const setData = async (key, value) => {
  const item = await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, value);
  return item;
}
```